# mod_rewrite and multiple RewriteBases?

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite

How can I set the rewrite base of the rewrite engine to

```
#access site via http://1.1.1.1/~sitename/
RewriteBase /~sitename/
```

when it's accessed via http://1.1.1.1/~sitename/ and set it to

```
#access site http://www.sitname.com
RewriteBase /
```

when it's accessed via www.sitname.com?

I'd like to have some sort of switch or condition. Because now when I set the RewriteBase to one of the options, the site is not functional when trying to access it with the other url.

**EDIT:** New site same problem.... so is this unsolvable?

Answer (score 1):

Put it withing  tags in you config. Something along the lines of the following might do:

```
<Directory /path/to/document/root>
    RewriteBase /
    ....
</DirectoryMatch>

<Directory /home/sitename>
    RewriteBase /~sitename
    ....
</DirectoryMatch>
```

For the ~sitename case you may want to place it in a .htaccess istead to more easily define it for different users.

If these are in different vhosts you also have to specify

```
RewriteEnging On
```

for both of them.

Comment: In fact this rule is in the .htaccess, also I can't get this to not create a server error.